# How to diagnose a python process chewing CPU in linux

Tags: linux, gdb, cpu-usage

My python process at certain point in automated scripts starts chewing CPU  on Linux based System (Ubuntu).
I’m trying to debug this issue in GDB. I'm fairly new to GDB.
Are there any GDB commands to give information on which thread is using most of the cpu.
Looking at the thread stack doesn't really give that away.

On windows windbg world  the command  '!runaway'  did give the info on time consumed by each thread in a process. 
Do we've an equivalent command  here ? 
Any other suggestions to debug issue ?

Comment: What you want, at this point, is a profiler. I'd start with one implemented in and for Python -- you'll get better information that way with lower-level tools. Jumping straight to gdb is almost certainly the wrong place to start.

Comment: ...and while "which profiler should I use for Python?" is a tool recommendation request and off-topic under SO's current rules, that question has been asked and answered back before those rules went into effect, so you'll find plenty of information in the archives.

Answer (score 18):

Just to clarify all the steps required to diagnose this issue. (thanks everyone for postings) :

Following command shows the list of process with their CPU / Memory usage :

```sh
$ ps auxf
```

Following command gives the list of all threads of a process sorted with CPU usage:

```sh
$ top -H -p [PID]

*PID     USER   PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU    %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND*
**1654** root   20   0 1416m 1.2g  24m t  **100** 36.8  21:26.23 python
1687     root   20   0 1416m 1.2g  24m t    0     36.8   0:05.07 python
```

Thread **1654** is chewing CPU. Attach `gdb` to the process:

```sh
$ gdb /path/of/executable [pid]
```

Following command in `gdb` to get list of threads:

```sh
(gdb) info threads

2  Thread 0xa7bffb40 (LWP 20736)    "python" 0xb7736424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
1  Thread 0xb73a56c0 (LWP **1654**) "python" 0xb7736424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
```

In `gdb` switch to the thread to check its stack:

```
(gdb) thread 1
(gdb) bt
```

Comment: Excellent.  Is there a way to tell which tread is eating the CPU?

Comment: what do you mean /path/of/process in this command? ```gdb /path/of/process [pid]```

Comment: @nngeek `/bin/python`.

Comment: Another way to do this is with `ps -eLf` which prints `LWP` in the fourth column, and how much time it ate a few more columns over.

Comment: When you've got a lot of threads and you don't want to search for the LWP visually, instead of using `info threads`, you can have gdb do the work for you: `thread find 1654`.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use the command top with the option to display all threads:

```
> top -H
```

The tasks will be sorted by CPU usage by default.

Alternate solutions can be found in the previous thread [here](https://superuser.com/questions/80556/how-do-you-view-all-threads-running-on-linux).

Comment: `top -H -p PID` is better.  `-p : Monitor only processes with given process id. This flag can be given up to twenty times. `

Comment: thank you guys. this was helpfull figure out which thread chewed cpu.

Comment: is there a gdb command to detect thread usage in a core-dump file. The assumption is that the process is not in the state where the process is chewing CPU. In fact this could be a core-dump from a customer.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

1. $ **top -H**

   | PID | USER | PR | NI | VIRT | RES | SHR | S | %CPU | %MEM | TIME+ | COMMAND |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | **1654** | root | 20 | 0 | 1416m | 1.2g | 24m | R | **100** | 36.8 | 21:26.23 | python |
   | 1687 | root | 20 | 0 | 1416m | 1.2g | 24m | S | 0 | 36.8 | 0:05.07 | python |
2. **q**
3. $ **gdb -p 1654**
4. (gdb) **bt**

## Long answer

#### top -H

Run `top -H` to show the threads consuming the most CPU on your machine. (Without -H, top normally shows a single PID for each group of threads.) If you have a runaway thread, you'll see it at the top of the list. Note its PID.¹

```
*PID     USER   PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU    %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND*
**1654** root   20   0 1416m 1.2g  24m R  **100** 36.8  21:26.23 python
1687     root   20   0 1416m 1.2g  24m S    0     36.8   0:05.07 python
```

#### Back to the prompt

Hit `q` to quit top. (Alternately, you may open a second terminal window.)

#### gdb -p **[pid]**

Run gdb using the -p option to tell it to attach to the PID of the thread you want to diagnose. You will get a (gdb) prompt.

```
$ gdb -p 1654
(gdb)
```

#### bt

At the (gdb) prompt, type `bt` to see the backtrace. The most useful gdb commands for examining the call stack and variables are: `up`, `down`, `list`, and `p`. (I also highly recommend `set print pretty on` so the output from `p` is easier to read.)

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000057279a in std::_Hashtable<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey, std::pair<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey const, terminal::renderer::ImageRenderer::Metadata>, std::allocator<std::pair<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey const, terminal::renderer::ImageRenderer::Metadata> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey>, std::hash<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::_M_find_before_node(unsigned long, terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey const&, unsigned long) const
    (this=this@entry=0x1c11780, __bkt=__bkt@entry=69247, __k=..., __code=11352315644114232719) at /usr/include/c++/10/bits/hashtable.h:1577
#1  0x0000000000573638 in std::_Hashtable<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey, std::pair<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey const, terminal::renderer::ImageRenderer::Metadata>, std::allocator<std::pair<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey const, terminal::renderer::ImageRenderer::Metadata> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey>, std::hash<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::_M_find_node(unsigned long, terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey const&, unsigned long) const
    (__c=11352315644114232719, __key=..., __bkt=69247, this=0x1c11780) at /usr/include/c++/10/bits/hashtable.h:693
#2  std::_Hashtable<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey, std::pair<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey const, terminal::renderer::ImageRenderer::Metadata>, std::allocator<std::pair<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey const, terminal::renderer::ImageRenderer::Metadata> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey>, std::hash<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::find(terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey const&) (__k=..., this=0x1c11780) at /usr/include/c++/10/bits/hashtable.h:1454
#3  std::unordered_map<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey, terminal::renderer::ImageRenderer::Metadata, std::hash<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey>, std::equal_to<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey>, std::allocator<std::pair<terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey const, terminal::renderer::ImageRenderer::Metadata> > >::find(terminal::renderer::ImageFragmentKey const&) (__x=..., this=0x1c11780) at /usr/include/c++/10/bits/unordered_map.h:920
...
```

## Minor caveat

If you attach to an individual thread using `gdb -p` as I suggest here, gdb will act as if there is only one thread. You must [attach](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Attach.html#Attach) to the main process's PID if you wish to use the `thread` command to switch which thread you are debugging.

---

¹ *Why do I say "PID" (process ID) instead of "TID" (thread ID)? Because, in Linux, threads are simply Lightweight Processes and use the same internal structure in the kernel as processes. Every new thread created has a different PID from the parent PID. To group them logically as a single "process", each thread has another field called TGID (Thread Group ID) which remembers the parent PID.*

Comment: Nice job laying that out + formatting, very clean and well organized.