# Does linux core dumps have thread cpu usage information

Tags: linux, multithreading, cpu-usage, coredump

Since I'm fairly new to linux and core dumps, I'm not sure what kind of information is stored in core-dumps. It makes me wonder if there is a GDB command to retrieve CPU % usage of threads from a Core dump file. Like the CPU % usage you get from 'top' command. Would be also nice to get memory usage too.

I'm rephrasing the question from my previous posting to stay more focused to the answer I'm looking for.
Reference : [How to diagnose a python process chewing CPU in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838498/how-to-diagnose-a-python-process-chewing-cpu-in-linux)

Comment: What do you mean by "usage"? If you mean detailed information on where each thread spent its time, the answer is definitely no.

Comment: I meant cpu % usage. Like The information you get when you run 'top' command. I'm particularly interested in capturing thread which is chewing higher cpu. Basically figure that out in a core dump.

Comment: What's the context? Is your bug in a C module, or in native Python code? Because really, you should be using a profiler for this kind of problem, not gdb.

Comment: In my case the code is in Python but this question is independent of that. Profiling is definitely a good idea to diagnose cpu chewing issues during Development phase. But I'm considering the scenario where I got a dump from customer site and I want to take a look at the thread cpu usage.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible to obtain info about the CPU usage from a coredump.

The coredump is just the snapshot of the memory of the process at death-time. Any dynamic history is not available: CPU make/model/frequency, system load, number of other processes, kernel scheduling info, etc.

As a side effect, you DO get the memory usage information, as long as you know the memory available on the system that generated the coredump: since the coredump is the memory of the process, the more memory the process used, the bigger the coredump (generally speaking, there are exceptions like regions of memory not included in the codedump).

Comment: Bart Polot,  Thanks for response. I'm surprised core dump doesn't collect this information. Specifically when the dump is generated manually of a run away process this information would be usefull. Somehow windows memory dumps does have some of this information. I recollect running !runaway command in windbg to get this information. Also remember seeing OS and architecure information.

Answer (score 1):

A core dump is a copy of the crashed process's address space (memory).  You can use it to see how much memory the process was using (and you can examine all the data in its memory at the time it crashed), but it doesn't contain any information about CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

For the future, you can collect this easily enough -- have your process periodically collect memory usage for each thread, and when debugging, hunt for that variable in the core.